# Tool(s) to + column & rows on HTML5 tables

Tags: html, html-table

I was about to fork a compatibility guide & when I looked at the HTML, I saw it was a table.

Tables are good to show data like this, but not fun to edit when you have to edit every few weeks.

**What tools can edit an existing HTML table very quickly & cleanly add/remove/clone columns & rows quickly & painlessly please?**

Can be online, GUI or WYSIWYG (prefered) or command-line driven, on or off-line (though online with JavaScript engine that is Node.js compatible is preferred).

Or perhaps another way is better to show tabular data that changes every few weeks, like AJAX presenting JSON data, but still need some hand-holding for the best scenario here also.

Table & suggestion in question:
https://github.com/kangax/es5-compat-table/blob/gh-pages/es6/index.html

https://github.com/kangax/es5-compat-table/issues/29

Comment: Are you asking what the best HTML editor is? Otherwise, you'd need to rewrite the page in PHP or whatever, so you can populate the table from a database. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Mr: Thanks for the questions; I've clarified my original for you. I'm visioning more o WYSIWYG HTML editor that specializes or has the ability to take an existing table & add/remove/clone columns & rows with a few clicks.  But a command-line "clone column 3" can work also.  Yes perhaps we need to separate out the data from presentation (may be done client-side via JavaScript), but for this occasional editing that might be too much.  But then if we want to add an API...

Answer (score 3):

Different people has different needs and attitudes!

1).You can use a spreadsheet program to edit the table and export to html.Google spreadsheet provides functionality to embed a preadsheet to a web page or to download(export) the spreadsheet in simple HTML, you can use CSS to style it to fit your needs.

2).Google's API can grab data from a spreadsheet and show like a table.What you have to do is just edit the Google spreadsheet!

I checked the API and could build a quick example,Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EgY22/)!

Here is a little summery of what I did,

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ&pub=1');
```

The spread sheet I refer here is http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ

```
  // Apply query language.
  //I'm selecting all the cols!
  query.setQuery('SELECT * ');
// Send the query with a callback function.
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
```

in my callback,

```
var data = response.getDataTable();
   //init the table
  visualization = 
   new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  visualization.draw(data, null);
```

Comment: I refered this[link] https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Setting_the_Query_from_JavaScript to build that fiddle!

Comment: Try simply  replacing my spreadsheet with your own spreadsheet! You will get a beautiful Table.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful info to know for my existing Google spreadsheets.  However, this is not useful for the project linked above, since there seems to be not HTML table import feature.  The most work I want to do is copy, paste, click click, copy paste.

Comment: Create a  new spreadsheet( creating a new spreadsheet is will take some effort but only for the first time. After that, you can simply update the spreadsheet, right?). Then " File=> Download as => HTML". A new window will open with our table and just copy past  the HTML code from that to your site. OR simply copy my codes from the fiddle and put in to your site change the spreadsheet link, then every time you edit the spread sheet the table in your site will automatically update!